# El css animate que aplico lo hace al revés en un formulario de login

Tags: css, login, animate.css

el animate css que he puesto lo hace al revés, lo aplica al fondo en lugar de aplicarlo al formulario, por lo que primero muestra el formulario de Login y luego el fondo que he puesto, no consigo ver que he escrito mal.

```
HTML
    {% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang = "es-ES" dir = "ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'style/master.css' %}">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css">
        <title>PETABYTES-DATOS</title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{% static 'imagenes/Anagrama.ico' %}">          
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="entrada.html">
            <div class="login-box animate__zoomIn">
                <img class="avatar" src="{% static 'imagenes/AnagramaT.png' %}" alt="Logo de Petabytes-Datos">
                <div>
                    <h5>ACCESO</h5>
                    <input class="controls" type="text" name = "usuario" value="" placeholder="Usuario">
                    <input class="controls" type="password" name = "santo" value="" placeholder="Contraseña">
                    <button class="buttons" type="submit" >Entrar</button>
                </div>
                <div class="recuerdos">
                    <a href="#">¿Recuerdas tu contraseña?</a>
                    <br><br><br>
                    <a href="#">Registro</a>
                </div>
            </div>          
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

master.css

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url(../imagenes/Agujero_negro_real_1200x800.png) no-repeat center top;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
.login-box{
    width: 320px;
    height: 420px;
    background: #3A3B3C;
    color: #fff;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position:absolute;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 70px 30px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border: solid #08F0FC;
    border-width: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.login-box .avatar{
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    top: -40px;
    left: 125px;
}


.login-box input{
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.login-box .controls {    
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 16px;
}
```

Lo que quiero es que el formulario de Login saliera del centro del navegador, como indico con el `animate__zoomIn`.
Algo he puesto al revés, seguro, pero después de poner la correspondiente clase en otros lugares sigo sin el efecto deseado.
Gracias.

Comment: No se entiende que es exactamente lo que quieres, y cuál es el problema. Cómo haces la animación? Con CSS o JS? No está ninguno. Y la estructura HTML es algo confuso.

Comment: Es la estructura del HTML lo que no me queda claro. Lo que pretendo con el animate.css es que el login-box salga desde el centro del navegador, ahora sale por abajo cuando el estilo es animate__zoomIn. Tendrá que ver como he diseñado la estructura y como he puesto la imagen de fondo (?)